# Acess to wolfram alpha datasets or something similar

Tags: wolframalpha

Wolfram alpha has datasets and functions for quite a variety of topics. I'm wondering if there is a way to programatically access/browse its knowledge graph other than the wolfram alpha search interface?

On another note, what is the closest open source project to wolfram alpha that has all sorts of different entities connected together like wolfram alpha does.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is referred to as a *query API*. Check out [Wolfram|Alpha Webservice API Reference](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html).

Another project that I know of is [Freebase](https://developers.google.com/freebase).

Comment: yeah but I wouldn't be able to get the data would I? I'm guessing they get it from a variety of paid sources so its not quite feasible.

Comment: Yes, you will be able to get search result data back. With Wolfram Alpha it's a paid service. Freebase is free, even for commercial use (with some restrictions I think)

Comment: No I don't want search results, I want all data. e.g all weather Data, all word data e.t.c

Comment: Then freebase is your best bet, you can download archives of Triplets that is sorted by subject and field. It's 22 GB gzipped, just [explore here](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data)